# magento: fetching MPN( manufacturer part no ) or UPC (Universal product code)

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I tried searching for MPN and UPC in the magento 1.4 - 1.5  database. Seems they're non existent or may be named differently. In which table can i find these values? i tried this

```
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->load(); 

    <mpn><![CDATA['. $product['mpn'] .']]></mpn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento comes stock with SKU (your in-store part number) defined.

For adding UPC or manufacturer part numbers, you will need take advantage of Magento's "out of the box" extensibility and add these as custom product attributes.

Comment: Brand will probably have to be added as an attribute as well. It's been so long ago, I can't remember if Manufacturer came stock (just under weight on the first product page), if so, it was a dropdown list and you have to go add manufacturers in on the attribute options list in attribute management so they'll show in the dropdown.

Comment: Read some documentation surrounding magentos attribute system or you will find yourself hurting later.